# Need advice for database design for statistics

Tags: mysql

Right now I'm building an ecommerce site and there will be statistics using Laravel and MariaDB.

My question is:
Right now I have Transactions and Transaction Summary table. Every time  transaction is made I will save to those tables.

Do I really need Transaction Summary tables to increase my speed when load statistics page (I don't need to `SUM` all the transactions amount)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience shows that it is good idea to summarize a big table to a statistic table. It can be done by scheduling a query runs when the mysql load is low every day or every week and update the statistic table.

Also you can keep only recent records of last month or last year and move the other records to another table to speed up statistic queries.

Comment: hi, thanks for rep. Which one you think is better, run a cron job every midnight and summarize  (each product) transaction or keep update the table when there is transaction?

Comment: @SSuhat my opinion is if keeping the table up to date accomplished by a simple and fast query then it is better but if it takes time then running a cron is better because it will not slow down the transactions.